# Determining probability of rain based on total probability in given week

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

The probability of rain in a given week is $2/7$. How do you find probability it will rain for exactly 4 days ?

I used the formula as
 $({}^7C_4) \cdot (0.28)^4 \cdot (0.72)^3$ 
 here, where the probability of rain $= 2/7 = 0.28$
 and the probability of no rain = $(1-0.28) = 0.72$

Not sure my math is right or wrong. Need suggestion to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like finding the number of binary numbers with seven digits, four of them being ones.

As you have guessed, it is a case where the convenient model is Binomial distribution $B(n,p)=B(7,p)$ in which you are interest by the event where the random variable "number of rainy days = X" is equal to 4. We know that, with this model:

$$\tag{1}P(X=4)=\binom{7}{4}p^7(1-p)^4,$$

but with which $p$ ? Here is where we disagree. I don't have the same $p$ as you:

For me, the value of $p$ is determined by constraint:

$$\text{Probability of at least a rainy day in the week} \ = 1-\underbrace{(1-p)^7}_{\text{not a single rainy day}}=2/7$$

$$\iff p=1-(5/7)^{1/7}=0.0469 \ \ \text{(not very simple !)}$$

It remains to plug this value of $p$ into (1) to obtain the result.

Comment: thank you very much. Now I get this clearly